# value toInt is not a member of Array[String] error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, text-files

I want to read each line from a text file, split it and convert it from Array[String] to Array[int] but i get

> value toInt is not a member of Array[String]

I know there are similar topics but it seems none one explains why this error occurs and the right way to use toInt.
Can anyone help me?

My code is

```
val textFile = sc.textFile(inputFile)
val splitRdd = textFile.map(line => line.split("  ")).map(_.toInt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this val `splitRdd = textFile.map(line => line.split("  "))` you get `RDD[Array[String]]`

So there is no function `toInt` in `Array`, so `.map(_.toInt)` can't be used

You need to use `flatmap` to get the flatten elements

```
val splitRdd = textFile.flatmap(line => line.split("  "))
```

This will give you `RDD[String]` and now you can use, `map(_.toInt)` to convert each element to `Integer`

```
val splitRdd = textFile.flatmap(_.split("  ")).map(_.toInt)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> split it and convert it from Array[String] to Array[int]

Then `map` the result of `split`:

```
val splitRdd: RDD[Array[Int]] = textFile.map(
  line => line.split("  ").map(_.toInt)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use flatMap instead of map to get RDD[String]:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val textFile = sc.textFile("test.txt")
val splitRdd = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(_.toInt)
splitRdd.collect()

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

textFile: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = test.txt MapPartitionsRDD[22] at textFile at <console>:28
splitRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = MapPartitionsRDD[24] at map at <console>:29
res12: Array[Int] = Array(123, 21312, 123, 2342, 2342, 23, 2342, 234, 234, 7657, 456754)

scala>
```

Comment: Me neither as it does what is requested by @user3121051.